# What is a "Server Build"

Tags: installation, hardware

I have a client asking if I have experience with "Server Builds".  Can anyone give me more info on what this means?  I've built many linux and windows servers for different uses, but I want to make sure I understand what that term means.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask them. Really. It can have subtle differences in meaning since people who don't know may coin the term or steal it and twist it for their own purposes.

Usually it just means you installed and configured a system to act as a server.

As them, clarifying that you'd build many Linux and Windows servers that acted as XYZ.

There's nothing wrong in an interview-type situation with clarifying what the person wants to know. You won't look like an idiot unless you *don't* ask, since you already seem to know the basic definition. Now you need to know if *they* know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it means getting the OS installed, updated, configured, and all the services up and running.  It also probably includes picking out proper hardware.  Basically it means server administration.

Answer (score 1):

They may mean that they want to know if you've had experience working on a team that does, or perhaps only coordinates, server builds. I worked for an enormous pharma company that did 10-15 server builds a week just in the northeast - there was a team of folks responsible for coordinating the whole flow done by other teams, from purchase to racking to cabling to storage to building the OS (which some people would consider the "build") to layered products (AV, backups, scheduling) to the "release to the business". Took four weeks, 1-2 weeks expedited.

They may also mean they want to know if you've had experience creating such a process.